# What is the correct way to set a cookie expiration when using Azure AD to login users to an ASP.NET Core 5 Web Application?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

We are creating an ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC project with authentication being handled with Azure AD, so we need to make API calls with `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp`, which then allows us to inject the `GraphServiceClient`. I am struggling to either debug or set the cookie expiration time. Ultimately, the cookie expiration needs to be two days in the future.

I have the following code that attempts to expire the OIDC cookie via the `ExpireTimeSpan` option. However, the cookie is not expiring like it should after one minute. Per the reference below, it appears that there may be a minimum of a 1 hour expiration that is set by Azure.

What is the correct way to set a cookie expiration when using Azure AD to login users to a Web Application? Is this a configuration that needs to be set within the Azure web portal or can we do it programmatically?

```csharp
Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
    {
        this.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAD").Bind(options);
    }
    , cookieAuthOptions =>
    {
        cookieAuthOptions.Cookie.Name = "MyWebAppName.Auth";
        cookieAuthOptions.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        cookieAuthOptions.SlidingExpiration = true;
    }
    );

    Services.AddRazorPages().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
    Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
    Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    Services.AddGraphServiceClient(this.Configuration);
```

Reference: https://yousry.medium.com/the-mystery-of-session-timeout-in-asp-net-core-3-1-5-70bb854fe168

**Edit: Bounty debug assistance request**

Please show how to set a watch for the cookie in Visual Studio so that I can inspect the cookie expiration time. I attempted to use the method that was mentioned in the reference above without success.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50258793/aspnetcore-openid-cookies-always-show-expires-1969-12-31-even-with-ispersistent) useful to you ?

Comment: @JasonPan No, it does not because we are using `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out after stumbling across the following post:

https://brokul.dev/authentication-cookie-lifetime-and-sliding-expiration

There was another post on SO that I found that mentioned there are two types of cookies being set: `session` and `authentication`. Unfortunately, I closed the page before figuring this all out, so I am unable to properly cite it.

Anyways, the problem boiled down the fact that I was missing the authentication cookie's `MaxAge` property.

I added some rather verbose comments to point of observer, and unwanted, behavior when experimenting with different configs. I decided that this provides the best user experience while also eliminating `correlated` and `nonce` cookies (i.e., `cookieAuthOptions.SlidingExpiration = false;`).

I hope others find this useful. It took a lot of trial-and-error as reading to figure out what is going on under the hood.

```csharp
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(authOptions =>
{
    this.Configuration.Bind("AzureAD", authOptions);
    authOptions.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(2);
}
, sessionOptions =>
{
    // This appears to be obsolete. Don't use it because you get the following error | OptionsValidationException: Cookie.Expiration is ignored, use ExpireTimeSpan instead.
    //sessionOptions.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(-1);

    // Setting the MaxAge will convert Expiration Date on the cookie from 'Session' to an actual future date and will show the default expiration date that is 14 days in the
    // future. However, note that the session cookie is different from the Authentication cookie, who's MaxAge is set in the AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp extension method above 
    // with an expiration that is equal to the session cookie's expiration. Additionally, we set the SlidingExpiration to false. These three configurations are considered the
    // safest and most secure. Otherwise, not setting the MaxAge while leaving the SlidingExpiration false results in CORS policy errors on the console after the session
    // cookie has expired. 
    // Reference: https://brokul.dev/authentication-cookie-lifetime-and-sliding-expiration
    sessionOptions.Cookie.MaxAge = cookieAuthOptions.ExpireTimeSpan;
    sessionOptions.Cookie.Name = "SomeProjectName.Auth";
    sessionOptions.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);

    // Keep this false and never change it to true. The problem with SlidingExpiration enabled is that the authentication cookie could be potentially re-issued infinitely.
    // That's not a good security practice. If a hacker took control of the account, they could use it forever.
    sessionOptions.SlidingExpiration = false;
});
```

Comment: One thing to point out here is that the `MaxAge` has a limit (I don't remember what it is) that if set too far out into the future then you will get an MaxAge out of range issue. In other words, a `MaxAge` of 2 days will give an error while a `MaxAge` of 2 hours is OK.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you'll like my response, but I'd like to answer this in a way that improves your future capabilities.

**OAUTH TECHNOLOGIES**

I work with these for a living and they are all about HTTP messages. To fully understand what is happening you need to be able to view request and responses completely. Browser tools and IDEs such as Visual Studio Code are less useful.

**OPEN SOURCE PROXY TOOLS**

I used to work on Windows and used the [Fiddler tool](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/configuredotnetapp#configure-net-core-applications) to view in-flight requests. My [blog post](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/http-debugging-setup/) explains how to use this type of tool for various technologies and application types, since I consider it to be an essential part of an effective developer setup.

**RESULTS**

You will then have complete visibility of what is happening under the hood, which you do not have when configuring a library in C# code. See [step 6 of this blog post](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/), which inspects how a cookie is set, including the expiry time.

**DOT NET**

I used to work with C# pretty heavily and I think Jason Pan's answer is on the right tracks. The way I would resolve this is to first trace HTTP messages, to see what the current expiry time being set is. I would then make his suggested code changes, then retrace HTTP messages, until I found an option that resulted in the desired behaviour.

**COOKIE EXPIRATION**

The cookie layer is actually nothing to do with OAuth. It is an application specific way of storing tokens and keeping them out of the browser. So no Azure AD settings will influence the cookie expiry time. You should aim to see what is happening as a first step. In the past I've also discovered things by digging around in [Microsoft cookie handler source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Unfortunately, this doesn't help me as Microsoft seems to have changed how cookies are managed when building a web application to rely on Azure AD to authenticate users through OIDC. I am still scratching my head on all of the different variations of authentication that are available.