# with azure b2c and blazor server, how to refresh user claim without disconnecting the websocket?

Tags: c#, blazor, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-server-side, claims-based-identity

I'm struggling to find how to refresh the user claim in blazor server while using b2c (Microsoft.Identity.Web) silently, without user intervention

as an example, I would like to refresh the claim expiry of the user, when it expire

biggest problem that I have is any search seem to bring up blazor WASM solution which are not good in my situation

my current test case is I got a expiry of 6 minutes and action are still accepted after many hours (so it should not be accepted)

Comment: Set the cookie expiration time.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70981046/what-is-the-correct-way-to-set-a-cookie-expiration-when-using-azure-ad-to-login

Comment: @jdweng this doesnt work with blazor server with an active websocket, once the user is in, the cookie is never read again until the user hit F5

Comment: Read following : https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/31232

Comment: @jdweng, my issue is not about cookie, it's about the user claims. I want to update it silently without having the user to do anything or lose the current state of the application. for an example, if i use **ITokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync**, I can see that the user get a new id token with a newer expiry but the user claims doesnt get updated

Comment: The database is a slave and the database will not automatically send new data.  Only way is to create an event that queries the database for updates.